# showmodaldialog function in ie8

Tags: jsp-tags

i have written a `showmodaldialog()` function in a jsp file and its working well in Firefox but in ie8 its now working,my code is here :

```
<-----a.jsp------>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Step Editor</title>
<script language=javascript>
function test() {
var retvalue;
retvalue = window.showModalDialog("index.jsp");

}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<input type=button value=Activity onclick=test()>
</body>
</html>

<--------->
```

in the above code a.jsp is parent window which is calling index.jsp as child window.

```
<----index.jsp----->
```

Comment: You called it window.showModalDialog (uppercase M and D), but you initially referred to it as showmodaldialog()

Also, did you attach it to the window object in your jsp file?

Comment: Oops, also, you should try adding quotes to all the parameters, e.g., type="button" and especially script type="text/javascript" instead of script language=javascript

Comment: The page as defined above (minus the @page statement) works fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

use `"<base target="_self" />"` in meta tag